# is possible to link a DNS name to another DNS name in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm kind of new on docker. I want to resolve DNS name into something define by the user. I mean, I have a service in docker which requires another service located in 'myEndpoint'. I want to configure that when the service asked to 'myEndpoint' returns an IP/FQN I decide, either in the containers or outside.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to map `myEndpoing` to a specific IP, you could use option `--add-host` when `docker run ...` your container. Take a look at the following example:

```
 ~/ docker run --add-host=myEndpoint:123.124.125.126 --rm alpine:3.3 ping myEndpoint -c 4
PING myEndpoint (123.124.125.126): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 123.124.125.126: seq=0 ttl=37 time=0.522 ms
64 bytes from 123.124.125.126: seq=1 ttl=37 time=0.391 ms
64 bytes from 123.124.125.126: seq=2 ttl=37 time=2.161 ms
64 bytes from 123.124.125.126: seq=3 ttl=37 time=0.488 ms

--- myEndpoint ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.391/0.890/2.161 ms
```

You can refer to [the docs of docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) for more details.

But if you want to map `myEndpoint` to other domain name, I think you need to use a FQDN and configure it as a CNAME DNS record, then configure DNS server for your container with option `--dns` options when you do `docker run ...`. Hope this could be helpful :)